# useSelector not working with getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux, state-management

I am using a simple next app, where i am fetching data from an api using getServerSideProps and after fetching the data is dispatched to reducer from a page. I am using a component , where useSelector is used. but the useSelector return only initial state but not the data fetched from api, i used debug to check the store. the store has the data. The data is in array of objects format.